# Where is the TFS build process going?

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild, workflow-foundation

Im having a hard time figuring out what the best approach is when designing my build process. It seems Microsoft have turned things around (again).

I am using TFS 2015 and Visual Studio 2015. For earlier versions of TFS I have normally created custom code activities that I plug in to my build definition process file (xaml). I like this approach because it gives me great flexibility and enables me to code .NET classes. I used these guides: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647551(v=vs.120).aspx

http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/29/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-4-Create-your-own-activity.aspx

In TFS 2015 it seems that there is no documentation on how to create custom code activities. In fact, it seems that Microsoft have changed things and now focuses on scripting languages in stead of custom .NET code: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Build/steps/index.

I have created a custom code activity and it seems to be working in TFS 2015 (with a few hacks) so it is still possible, but I am nervous that this approach is no longer the way to go.

Can anyone provide information about what is happening here?

Comment: In TFS 2015 support for XAML agents is still there, the process for extending the XAML services remains largely the same (though you may need to retarget to the right Client Object Model and .NET versions). But the XAML agent and activities are considered deprecated for VSTS and that indicates that they'll probably be removed in a future version of TFS as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TFS 2015 introduces new builds, which are web- and script-based, and highly customizable. Meanwhile, TFS 2015 will continue to support the XAML Build templates and controllers.

The new builds are based on a different architecture and run on a completely different system. Currently, you can use both the new builds and agents alongside your XAML builds, controllers, and agents.

**Which builds should I use?**

If you are new to Team Foundation Server (TFS) and Visual Studio Team Services, you should use this new system. Most customers with experience using TFS and XAML builds will also get better outcomes by using the new system.

The new builds are web- and script-based, and highly customizable. They leave behind many of the problems and limitations of the XAML builds. For example, this new system embraces the diverse set of domain-specific languages (DSLs) that developers used to build the code on their dev machines. We expect this will reduce the chances of running into the "builds fine on my machine but not on the CI server" problem.

If you have heavily customized XAML builds and custom activities, you can continue using those builds until you are ready to port your business logic into scripts that can run in the new builds.

Useful articles for your reference:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/02/12/build-futures/
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/build/feature-overview

Comment: Not that for VSTS new accounts are no longer provisioned with support for XAML builds and that the XAML support will be turned off in September 2016.

Comment: "This service will be retired by September 2016. Please plan to use the Build and Deployment service instead." https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/setup/get-more-build-or-load-testing-vs

Comment: If I should not use code activities any more, how can i hook into the build process? A concrete example: today one of my code activities is dependant on two variables, namely one that identifies that no build errors occurred and one that identifies that all my tests succeed. These variables are available within the build process. How are these available, if at all if I am to use a power shell build step? Im concerned that the flexibility I had before has been traded for an easy-to-use component based approach.

Comment: @Flodpanter, do you mean you want to use variables in build template? You may check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/build/scripts/variables

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I see that some of the variables that I have used in the past are still available.

Comment: @jessehouwing the page you link to indicates that only hosted XAML build controllers are going away.  Those running on-prem build controllers can continue on.

Comment: @christopherpainter they may continue to be supported for a while. They will not be receiving any update, no direct vs 2017 support, not the new test infrastructure, no Azure arm. They're dead for all future development.

Comment: TFS 2017 actually shows a deprecated warning on the installer page to confirm this.