# Where are the Powershell cmdlets for TFS 2017?

Tags: powershell, tfsbuild, powershell-cmdlet

I have a 2008 software with a `TFSBuild.proj` on a TFS repository that has been migrated from 2008 to 2017.  I have a TFS 2017 build agent on which has been installed Visual Studio 2017 (15.7.6).

There is only an automatic migration path from `TFSBuild.proj` to XAML builds.  But XAML builds have for three years already been in the process of going away, per "[Where is the TFS build process going?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36766826/)".  [In 2017 they require an older build agent from 2010 to 2013](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2017/05/30/evolving-tfsteam-services-build-automation-capabilities/), and I only have a 2017 build agent as I said (and 2008 build agents).

There is no automatic migration path to the somewhat unwisely named "vNext" build system.  (It's now "current", and rather obstructs naming Microsoft's *next* build system. 
 ☺)   So I have been writing my own build definition by hand, hand-converting what the old `TFSBuild.proj` used to do.

Some of what it used to do involved custom MSBuild tasks in a DLL written in-house, such as one using `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client` et al. to obtain the latest changeset for the latest successful build, by obtaining the latest label whose name matches a particular pattern and then looking at the changeset IDs of all of its items.  This seems like a shoo-in for another (I already have some.) nice little Powershell task in the "vNext" build definition, [calling the Powershell TFS cmdlets](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/04/21/powershell-and-tfs-the-basics-and-beyond/).

Except that these do not appear to be available now.  They were in the TFS Power Tools in earlier versions of TFS.  [The TFS 2017 release notes say that there are no Power Tools for TFS 2017, and claim that they have been integrated into TFS proper.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/releasenotes/tfs2017-relnotes#knownissues)  This does not appear to be the case for my TFS 2017 build agent:

```
PS C:\> Get-TfsServer
Get-TfsServer : The term 'Get-TfsServer' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-TfsServer
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-TfsServer:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\>
```

I'd rather have the Microsoft cmdlets if I can, rather than make my own, for the sake of the programmer that comes after me.  After all, I *am* that programmer, dealing with in-house extensions created for the build system before last.  ☺

So what are my options?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend doing some searches by doing **get-command *tfs***. If tfs really doesn't come with commands, consider looking at the psgallery. There are probably already cmdlets for tech you're trying to manage on the gallery.

Try: 
 **find-command *tfs*** or **find-module *tfs***